# Установка react

Tags: reactjs

Установил reac и node, но почему то при открытие приложения отдает данную страницу. Подскажите в чем может быть дело и как это поправить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

вы установили `react` и `node.js`, хорошо, а сервер подняли, все что надо запустили?

например: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial

посмотрите порядок действий, что надо сделать, чтобы react приложение заработало

если же все сделали, то что выдается в терминале? есть ли ошибки?

Comment: Я только начал осваивать, не совсем понимаю что к чему. До этого стоял node v10, при установке react, потребовалось обновить, обновил, установил react. Далее есть папка приложения по адресу /root/react-intro. node висит на порту 5000. Адрес по которому доступна страница ip:5000. Блин я не понимаю что делать, вроде сделал все как надо. А тестовое приложение элементарно не работает.  Я не могу как то даже начать писать, тестить и тд

Comment: а вы создайте простой react проект и посмотрите - он нормально запустится

Comment: https://ibb.co/CHmZ4vH при выполнении команды  npm start. Столько папок  и файлов, не понимаю что к чему и куда лезть

Comment: Как я понимаю, react установился как глобально? В любом случаи созданное приложение /root/react-intro должно работать.